# Reading and writing to serial port in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, tty

I'm trying to **send/receive data over an USB Port using FTDI**, so I need to handle serial communication using C/C++. I'm working on **Linux** (Ubuntu).

Basically, I am connected to a device which is listening for incoming commands. I need to send those commands and read device's response. Both commands and response are **ASCII characters**.

Everything works fine using GtkTerm but, when I switch to C programming, I encounter problems.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions

/* Open File Descriptor */
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY );

/* Error Handling */
if ( USB < 0 )
{
cout << "Error " << errno << " opening " << "/dev/ttyUSB0" << ": " << strerror (errno) << endl;
}

/* *** Configure Port *** */
struct termios tty;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

/* Error Handling */
if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
{
cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}

/* Set Baud Rate */
cfsetospeed (&tty, B9600);
cfsetispeed (&tty, B9600);

/* Setting other Port Stuff */
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;       // no flow control
tty.c_lflag     =   0;          // no signaling chars, no echo, no canonical processing
tty.c_oflag     =   0;                  // no remapping, no delays
tty.c_cc[VMIN]      =   0;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]     =   5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout

tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines
tty.c_iflag     &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);// turn off s/w flow ctrl
tty.c_lflag     &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
tty.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;              // make raw

/* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );

if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
{
cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << endl;
}

/* *** WRITE *** */

unsigned char cmd[] = {'I', 'N', 'I', 'T', ' ', '\r', '\0'};
int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd) -1 );

/* Allocate memory for read buffer */
char buf [256];
memset (&buf, '\0', sizeof buf);

/* *** READ *** */
int n = read( USB, &buf , sizeof buf );

/* Error Handling */
if (n < 0)
{
     cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}

/* Print what I read... */
cout << "Read: " << buf << endl;

close(USB);
```

What happens is that `read()` returns 0 (no bytes read at all) or block until timeout (`VTIME`). I'm assuming this happens because `write()` does not send anything. In that case, device wouldn't receive command and I cannot receive response. In fact, turning off the device while my program is blocked on reading actually succeded in getting a response (device sends something while shutting down).

Strange thing is that adding this

```
cout << "I've written: " << n_written << "bytes" << endl;
```

right after `write()` call, I receive:

```
I've written 6 bytes
```

which is exactly what I expect. Only my program doesn't work as it should, like **my device cannot receive what I'm actually writing** on port.

I've tried different things and solution, also regarding data types (I've tried using std::string, such as `cmd = "INIT \r"` or `const char`) but nothing really worked.

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Previously version of this code used

`unsigned char cmd[] = "INIT \n"`

and also `cmd[] = "INIT \r\n"`. I changed it because command sintax for my device is reported as

`<command><SPACE><CR>`.

I've also tried avoiding the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on reading, but then I only block until forever. I've tried using `select()` but nothing happens. Just for a try, I've created a waiting loop until data is avaliable, but my code never exit the loop. Btw, waiting or `usleep()` is something I need to avoid. Reported one is only an excerpt of my code. **Complete code needs to work in a real-time environment** (specifically OROCOS) so I don't really want sleep-like function.

Comment: `std::cout` is C++. Generally speaking, your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should stick to one language unless you suspect a bad interaction. Otherwise some folks start arguing C++ is not C.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I've solved my problems, so I post here the correct code in case someone needs similar stuff.

**Open Port**

```
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );
```

**Set parameters**

```
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

/* Error Handling */
if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 ) {
   std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}

/* Save old tty parameters */
tty_old = tty;

/* Set Baud Rate */
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

/* Setting other Port Stuff */
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

/* Make raw */
cfmakeraw(&tty);

/* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) {
   std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
}
```

**Write**

```
unsigned char cmd[] = "INIT \r";
int n_written = 0,
    spot = 0;

do {
    n_written = write( USB, &cmd[spot], 1 );
    spot += n_written;
} while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
```

It was definitely not necessary to write byte per byte, also `int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd) -1)` worked fine.

At last, **read**:

```
int n = 0,
    spot = 0;
char buf = '\0';

/* Whole response*/
char response[1024];
memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

do {
    n = read( USB, &buf, 1 );
    sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
    spot += n;
} while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

if (n < 0) {
    std::cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
else if (n == 0) {
    std::cout << "Read nothing!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Response: " << response << std::endl;
}
```

This one worked for me. Thank you all!

Comment: Your line `response.append(&buf);` doesn't compile for me. Neither does `while(buf != '\r' && n > 0);`. Are these typos or am I missing something?

Comment: The code you suggest for sending `int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd) -1)` doesn't really work for large buffers. In that case you'd need a loop like the one you show above, but with `n_written = write( USB, cmd + spot, command_length - spot)`. Also you'd have to use the length to terminate the loop, instead of checking each character individually.

Comment: `cfmakeraw()` already sets a bunch of attributes. You don’t need these lines:
    `tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;`

Comment: Why the cast of `(speed_t)` in `cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);`?  At worst, it silents a useful warning that the constant used does not fit in a `speed_t`.  At best, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some receivers expect EOL sequence, which is typically two characters `\r\n`, so try in your code replace the line

```
unsigned char cmd[] = {'I', 'N', 'I', 'T', ' ', '\r', '\0'};
```

with

```
unsigned char cmd[] = "INIT\r\n";
```

BTW, the above way is probably more efficient. There is no need to quote every character.

Comment: Also, some USB drives have fast write caching which means that it sits in a buffer before actually getting written right?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but `\r\n` is not my problem. I've tried it and nothing really changes. Other ideas?

Comment: @Lunatic999 I just read your code again and the line `int n_written = write( USB, cmd, sizeof(cmd) -1 );` kind of bothers me. Would you be willing to test using `int n_written = write(USB, cmd, strlen(cmd));` ? That's what I have in a program I worked on, very similar setup like yours, communication through a ttyUSB.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'd add a /n after init.  i.e. *write( USB, "init\n", 5);*

2) Double check the serial port configuration.  Odds are something is incorrect in there.  Just because you don't use ^Q/^S or hardware flow control doesn't mean the other side isn't expecting it.

3) ***Most likely:***  Add a *"usleep(100000);* after the *write()*.  The file-descriptor is set not to block or wait, right?  How long does it take to get a response back before you can call read?  (It has to be received and buffered by the kernel, through system hardware interrupts, before you can *read()* it.)  Have you considered using *select()* to wait for something to *read()*?  Perhaps with a timeout?

**Edited to Add:**

Do you need the DTR/RTS lines?  Hardware flow control that tells the other side to send the computer data?  e.g.

```
int tmp, serialLines;

cout << "Dropping Reading DTR and RTS\n";
ioctl ( readFd, TIOCMGET, & serialLines );
serialLines &= ~TIOCM_DTR;
serialLines &= ~TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl ( readFd, TIOCMSET, & serialLines );
usleep(100000);
ioctl ( readFd, TIOCMGET, & tmp );
cout << "Reading DTR status: " << (tmp & TIOCM_DTR) << endl;
sleep (2);

cout << "Setting Reading DTR and RTS\n";
serialLines |= TIOCM_DTR;
serialLines |= TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl ( readFd, TIOCMSET, & serialLines );
ioctl ( readFd, TIOCMGET, & tmp );
cout << "Reading DTR status: " << (tmp & TIOCM_DTR) << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I've tried what you suggest but nothing changed. I've edited my question with more information... Any other ideas? Thank you again

Comment: usleep() is just for debugging/testing.  Once it's working, you can switch to select() to wait just the necessary time for a response.

Comment: How did you write 7 bytes?  It's "INIT \r" which is 6 bytes...  Are you writing the trailing NULL character?  Some systems interpret a NULL character as end-of-communication...

Comment: Sorry, 7 bytes was my error in reporting it. I definitely write the right number of bytes (6). 7 was referring to an attempt with `\r\n` ending. I'll edit my question.
Anyway I've fixed everything and now it works. I will post the final code in case someone should need something similar.
Really thank you for you answers!