# How to find USB device port in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, usb

I have a USB device connected to my computer, it is this one:

[image]

I want to use it in Python according to the example in [this link](https://sensirion.github.io/python-shdlc-sensorbridge/quickstart.html). How do I know what to put for `port` (instead of `'COM1'`) in the line `with ShdlcSerialPort(port='COM1', baudrate=460800) as port:`?

Comment: not well researched there is a example for that try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049884/find-specific-usb-port-under-ubuntu

Comment: In that answer he just guesses that it is `/dev/ttyACM0`. In my system I don't see it so it does not work for me.

Comment: The [documentation](https://sensirion.github.io/python-shdlc-driver/api.html#sensirion_shdlc_driver.port.ShdlcSerialPort) gives a great hint on that.

Comment: Thank you @KlausD., however I don't have `/dev/ttyUSB0` either.

Comment: Then you should ask in one of sibling sites that covers this topic (maybe Linux in general). Setting up hardware is not a software developer task.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, as mentioned in another comment. Consider posting to SuperUser. Note that, when you repost, you should include properly-formatted text, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 2):

In linux, lsusb is a tool used to display information about the USB bus in the system and connected to the system. lsusb will display the drivers and internal devices connected to your system, including PID and VID, as well as simple device descriptions.

```
$ lsusb -v |grep -Ei ‘(idVendor|Mass\ Storage)’
idVendor 0×1005 Apacer Technology, Inc.
bInterfaceClass 8 Mass Storage
```

Output very detailed information, including the current of the device and so on. With the grep command to specify specific information, the mass storage device will have a vendor name and ID.

Bus 008: Indicate where the device is connected (which bus)
Device 002: Indicates that this is the second device connected to the bus
ID: ID of the device
Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller: Manufacturer name and device name

```
$ lsusb -t

/: Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/6p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=stor., Driver=usb-storage, 480M
|__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=’bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled’, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
|__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=’bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled’, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/: Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root\_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/6p, 480M
```

12M means that the speed of USB 1.0 / 1.1 is 12Mbit/s

480M means that the speed of USB 2.0 is 480Mbit/s

If you find 5.0G, it means you have a USB 3.0 type interface. It has a transmission rate of 5.0Gbit/s. Linux recognizes the detailed information of USB devices from /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids. Or you can visit Linux-USB.org to get the latest USB ID list.