# Linux C++ Serial Writing: Only one character written

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb

I'm trying to modify the code written here:[Linux C Serial Port Reading/Writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/linux-c-serial-port-reading-writing) so that I can control an LED flasher unit over a serial (with a usb adapter) connection. However, when I try to write the command of 12 ones to the device, and then I check the LED status with GTKterm and an oscilloscope, it appears as though the device is only receiving the first term, i.e. that it is receiving the command ("10000000000"). I believe the port settings are correct (although I could be entirely wrong) and have attached the following image of the commands running in GTKterm correctly !http://oi59.tinypic.com/27wrexx.jpg .Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?
Many thanks
Sam

My code:

```
int flasher::allon(){
  int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );
  struct termios tty;
  struct termios tty_old;
  memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

  /* Error Handling */
  if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
    {
      cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }

  /* Save old tty parameters */
  tty_old = tty;

  /* Set Baud Rate */
  cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
  cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

  /* Setting other Port Stuff */
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
  tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;  
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;       // no flow control
  tty.c_cc[VMIN]      =   1;                  // read doesn't block
  tty.c_cc[VTIME]     =   5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
  tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

  /* Make raw */
  cfmakeraw(&tty);

  /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
  tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
  if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
     {
       cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << endl;
     }

  unsigned char cmd[] = "111111111111 \r\n";
  int n_written = 0;

  do {
    n_written += write( USB, &cmd[n_written], 1 );
  }
  while (cmd[n_written-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
  int n = 0;
  char buf = '\0';

  /* Whole response*/
  std::string response;

  do
    {
      n = read( USB, &buf, 1 );
      response.append( &buf );
    }
  while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);

  if (n < 0)
    {
      cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
  else if (n == 0)
    {
      cout << "Read nothing!" << endl;
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Response: " << response<<endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you made the buffer just one character?

Comment: It was how the OP in the referenced thread did it, and he/she claimed it worked. Setting the write buffer to 12 and the read buffer to 25 doesn't help though.

Comment: It might work if you change one line from response.append(&buf) to response.push_back( buf );

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried it to no avail. A couple of characters appear to get through to the device and then the code just runs endlessly doing nothing. I've tried taking out the whole 'read' section of the thing to try and troubleshoot this problem with only a single character being written to the device, but it only improves the situation to two characters being written, and not twelve as I need.

Comment: it "runs endlessly" or it sits waiting for input that doesn't come? read() can be a blocking call.

Comment: I'm not sure, there should be input (the device returns the led status correctly in GTKterm).

Comment: The other code sets cc[VMIN]=0 but you have set it to 1

Comment: Well spotted! I've no idea how that happened, I didn't change it intentionally, changing it hasn't helped though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work for certain for this reason

`string` has an append function that takes a char* but it expects a null-terminated string. Your buf is just one character so if read() does put a character in it, there is no guarantee what follows it in memory, so you do not have a proper null-terminated string but undefined behaviour.

You should probably supply a buffer with more than 1 character and then use a version of `append` that takes a length, passing in n.

Otherwise replace

```
response.append( &buf );
```

with

```
response.push_back( buf );
```

which might work but is probably less efficient than using a multi-character buffer. You should probably check the result of `read` before appending it too. As the code stands, if `read` fails you append anyway.

This statement, if valid at all, should switch the order of the while clauses

```
while (cmd[n_written-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
```

if n_written is not > 0 then the LHS is undefined behaviour. So

```
while ( n_written > 0 && cmd[n_written-1] != '\r');
```

Are you sure that is the right condition to terminate the loop anyway? I assume `\r` is some kind of "message over" character.

If `write()` returned -1 it would not necessarily push `n_written` to or below 0.