# Posix Serial Port Raw Read hanging

Tags: c, linux, uart, beagleboneblack

I'm testing an UART application on the BeagleBone Black and when I try to read from the device it blocks forever. A write works fine. I hooked up a logic analyzer to inspect the line and I can see the data being transmitted and received, but it just always blocks on a read.

```
int main() {
  int res;
  struct termios tty;
  memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
  int serial = open("/dev/ser2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (!isatty(serial))
    return false;
  // Setting the Baud rate
  cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);
  // 8N1 Mode
  tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
  tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

  tty.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHONL | ISIG);
  tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  if ((tcsetattr(serial, TCSANOW, &tty)) != 0)
    return false;
  if ((tcflush(serial, TCIOFLUSH)) != 0)
    return false;

  while (1)
  {
    uint8_t wrBuff[3] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC};
    uint8_t res = write(serial, wrBuff, 3);
    printf("Write = %d", res);
    res = read(serial, wrBuff, 3);
    printf("Read = %d", res);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I attempted the fix mentioned in the comments below regards the [incorrect flag set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195829/ubuntu-serial-communication-reads-failing-and-then-coming-in-all-at-once) but this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Use `O_SYNC` with `open`. Also see [How to open, read, and write from serial port in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947413/608639) and [Reading and writing to serial port in C on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18108932/608639).

Comment: @jww I had tried `O_SYNC` flag before but open returns an error for some reason with that flag on QNX

Comment: @jww Using those examples provided above my read is still hanging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Serial Communication: reads failing and then coming in all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195829/ubuntu-serial-communication-reads-failing-and-then-coming-in-all-at-once).   Exact same bug, except your input does not have any EOLs, so read does not terminate.

Comment: @sawdust I fixed that bug but unfortunately the read is still hanging. In raw mode I dont need to send any EOL correct? Just sending the bytes shoudl suffice.

Comment: The initialization of the termios structure `tty` is improper, and then the code is illogical.  You zero-out the structure instead of a proper initialization by calling **tcgetattr()**.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  Then the code illogically clears attribute bits as if the structure had been properly initialized but was actually cleared.