# No data sent over serial port in linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, serial-port

TL;DR - I am attempting serial communication with Arduino with code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/linux-c-serial-port-reading-writing) and nothing gets sent over (Arduino programmed to respond, and I checked that it does with its serial monitor)

Hi there,
I was looking for a way to send information over to an Arduino Mega (2560) unit over linux serial port by C++.

I came across the following solution: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/linux-c-serial-port-reading-writing)
I'm using this guy's code for write (I'm able to read data from the arduino) and use the same parameters (they work, as I'm able to receive data from the Ardunio). 
I programmed my Arduino to send "Hi" over serial whenever it sees at least 1 bit of information, and checked it worked through the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor.

Yet when running the C++ code, the arduino doesn't respond. Do anyone might have idea why?

Full disclosure - I inserted @Lunatic999's code to a class so I can make an instance of it for my needs of the code.

```
fd = open(portNameC, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC); //open port ("opens file")
```

Serial Parameters:

```
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

/* Error Handling */
if ( tcgetattr ( fd, &tty ) != 0 ) {
   std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}

/* Save old tty parameters */
tty_old = tty;

/* Set Baud Rate */
cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B19200);
cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B19200);

/* Setting other Port Stuff */
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

/* Make raw */
cfmakeraw(&tty);

/* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
tcflush( fd, TCIFLUSH );
if ( tcsetattr ( fd, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) {
   std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
}
```

**Write** (this code I put inside a function which I call)

```
unsigned char cmd[] = "INIT \r";
int n_written = 0,
    spot = 0;

do {
    n_written = write( fd, &cmd[spot], 1 );
    spot += n_written;
} while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
```

Arduino code:

```
bool dataRecieved = false;
int ledpin = 13;

void setup() {
pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {  
  while(!dataRecieved)
  {
   digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH);
   if (Serial.available() > 0) 
   {
     dataRecieved = true;
   }
  }
  digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("hi");
}
```

Comment: The write syscall of just a single byte in a loop is needlessly inefficient.  Instead simply pass the entire string in one syscall, e.g `n_written = write(fd, cmd, strlen(cmd));`.  Then check the return value for error.

Comment: *"Do anyone might have idea why?"* -- Why does your serial terminal initialization code use variable `USB` as the file descriptor?  Whereas in the open and write code you use the variable `fd`.

Comment: @swadust Thanks for the comment. I tried:
        unsigned char *cmd[] = {"INIT"};
 int n_written = 0,
 cout<<"In Write Serial"<<endl;
 n_written = write(fd, cmd, strlen(cmd));
and got error:annot convert ‘unsigned char**’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’
  n_written = write(fd, cmd, strlen(cmd));

EDIT: otherwise I have to use write(fd, &cmd, strlen(cmd);

Comment: @sawdust I know, I haven't noticed it in this ver. In my code it uses fd, not USB, I'll change it so it is accurate. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an arduino problem all along. I needed to apply some usleep to let arduino bootload